# How to loop through an xml and add data to collection

Tags: wpf, xml, vb.net

I'm trying to just iterate through this xml and grab all of its data and add it to my collection(_personOC). Right now it's not working. How can I do this without having to specify the id? All I did was make a dataset with a person table and saved it as a xml. Any help is appreciated.

```
  Public Property personOC As ObservableCollection(Of Person)
    Get
        Return _personOC
    End Get
    Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of Person))
        _personOC = value

    End Set
End Property

Dim testdata As New TestData()
Dim person As Person
Public Sub New()

    Try
        Dim persondataset As New DataSet1
        persondataset.ReadXml("Person.xml", System.Data.XmlReadMode.ReadSchema)

        If persondataset.Tables.Count > 0 Then
            Dim dt() As DataRow = persondataset.Tables("Person").Select(String.Format("Id={0}", 0))

            With dt(0)

                _personOC.Add(New Person(.Item("FirstName"), .Item("LastName"), .Item("Age"), .Item("Gender")))
            End With

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Whey are you doing 3 transformations here? From `XML` To `DataSet` To `Collection`? Isnt that time consuming?
2. WPF binding work for all 3 types of data structures. So why not bind to the XML itself? Did you explore `Binding` object's `XPath` property that resolves XML elements directly from an XML?

Comment: Honestly, I did not know I could bind to the xml itself. Not sure how to

Comment: Please find examples on the internet of how to bind to XML in WPF.